# Failed to install SQL Server 2019 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to learn SQL to create my own database to serve for my future project but things seem not to be smooth as expected from the first step. I struggled with installing the SQL Server for days with different times of uninstalling and reinstalling. The installation Progress has just constantly thrown me warning window with the content was:

> The MOF compiler could not connect with the WMI server. This is either because of a semantic error such as an incompatibility with the existing WMI repository or an actual error such as the failure of the WMI server to start.

I believed that the old SQL Server was completely uninstalled by deleting anything related thing include files in Program Files, Program Files(x86), and its registry.

I searched and followed many threads with the same issue on some forums but still got no result.

After skipping that warning by canceling it, the installation completed with failure shown in the picture below. Your help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to install all of those features if you're just learning SQL? Just the Database Engine should be enough to start with.

Comment: Follow this tutorial: [How to install SQL Server Express edition](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-install-sql-server-express-edition/)

Comment: I've just installed it in the default order and keep all options unchanged. I just plan to learn SQL at first but all features install would be convenient for me to explore more. Also, I'm afraid that the inadequate will lead to some problem afterward.

Comment: @MaciejLos I did exactly as these instructions except changing some directory to another disk to save space for the C disk.